# Clickable HTML link labels for features in exported PDF

Tags: qgis, pdf, hyperlink

Is it possible to create a map in QGIS (version 2.18.15) exported to PDF that contains features with labels as an HTML link? By clicking on feature symbol or label this link should open in browser.

Answer (score 1):

No,this is currently not possible. A bug has been filed but is not resolved yet (QGis 3 should solve it hopefully):
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/10731